# iOS and Android native apps sharing React Native database

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I maintain an app that has iOS and Android native versions, and now I and my pairs are considering migrate both to React Native. We want to do this step by step, so in the first moment, we consider that a good approach would be implementing the data layer into React Native and make the native apps consume the data through this hybrid layer. Is this possible? Sorry if this is a silly question, I never had any experience with React Native.

EDIT: The database would be primarily realm-js because we already have experience with Realm on Android - iOS uses Coredata and this is a reason for choosing this approach as well, have 2 database technology on the mobile side gave us some headaches already.

Comment: Yes it is possible, and the setup is pretty easy.

Comment: Great, @HamzaJadid!
Do you have some examples or references that we should follow to achieve that?

Comment: yes I do have an example

Comment: @HamzaJadid could you share this example?

Comment: @robsonbbs Were you able to achieve what you need with this approach. We are planning to migrate our existing native apps to react native following the same approach

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example on how to setup realm

```js
import Realm from "realm";

// define your realm schemas
const TodoSchema: Realm.ObjectSchema = {
  name: "todo",
  primaryKey: "id",
  properties: {
    id: "int",
    title: { type: "string", default: "untitled" },
    body: { type: "string", default: "" },
    isDone: { type: "bool", default: false},
  },
};

interface ITodo {
  title: string;
  body: string;
  isDone?: boolean;
}

class RealmDao {
  private realmDao: Realm;

  private static instance: RealmDao | null = null;

  private constructor() {
    this.realmDao = new Realm({
      schema: [TodoSchema], // array of schemas
      schemaVersion: 0,
    });
  }

  // insuring that only one instance exists
  public static getInstance = () => {
    if (RealmDao.instance === null) {
      RealmDao.instance = new RealmDao();
    }

    return RealmDao.instance;
  };

  public insert = (tableName: string, todo: ITodo) => 
    this.realmDao.write(() => {
      this.realmDao.create("todo", tableName);
    });
  };

  public retrieveAll = (tableName: string) => {
    return this.realmDao.objects(tableName);
  };
}

const insert = (tableName: string, todo: ITodo) => {
  RealmDao.getInstance().insert(tableName, todo);
}

const retrieveAll = (tableName: string) => {
  RealmDao.getInstance().retrieveAll(tableName);
}

export { insert, retrieveAll };
```

Made it singleton to ensure that only one instance exists, I ran into a problem before where multiple instances of realm are running.

Now you can use the data in your component

```js
import React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";

import { insert, retrieveAll } from "./realmDao";

const Example = () => {
  React.useEffect(() => { insert({'title', 'something to be done'}); }, []);
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{JSON.stringify(retrieveAll ('todo'))}</Text>
    </View>
  )
);
```

Comment: Nice, thanks for sharing!
But what I really need is an example of how to invoke "RealmDao.loadAll('todo')" from a native app. 
I know that is possible to integrate a React Native components with an existing native app (https://reactnative.dev/docs/integration-with-existing-apps) but I don't know if it's possible to invoke custom JS classes like RealmDao from a native app.

Comment: check this https://reactnative.dev/docs/communication-ios#calling-react-native-functions-from-native-events